# How to get dynamic length for highest/lowest function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

for my trailing stop loss i need to know the highest (long) or lowest (short) that price has reached since i have entered the trade so i can have it not disarm my custom trails when price drops below this arm price again. for this i need to have the bars that i have been in a trade as a number, that number will be used as the length for the ta.highest function. Any help on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

The code below is how i thought i could get it working, but i get errors that the length of highest or lowest function can not be NaN and must be higher than 0.

```
// Configure trail stop level with input options
longTrailPerc = input.float(title='Trail Long Loss (%)', minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=2.2) * 0.01

shortTrailPerc = input.float(title='Trail Short Loss (%)', minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=2.2) * 0.01



// Determine trail stop loss prices
longStopPrice = strategy.position_avg_price*0.95
shortStopPrice = strategy.position_avg_price*1.05

if strategy.position_size > 0
    longStopPrice := if ta.highest(source=close, length=bar_index-strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades -1)) > strategy.position_avg_price *1.02
        stopValue=close*(1-longTrailPerc)
        math.max(stopValue, longStopPrice[1])

if strategy.position_size < 0
    shortStopPrice := if ta.lowest(source=close, length=bar_index-strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades -1)) > strategy.position_avg_price *0.98
        stopValue=close*(1+shortTrailPerc)
        math.min(stopValue, shortStopPrice[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the highest/lowest close yourself by using a `var`. Reset it when you enter a new trade and update its value during the trade.

```
var float highest_close = na
var float lowest_close = na

is_new_trade = (strategy.position_size[1] == 0 and strategy.position_size != 0) or (strategy.position_size[1] * strategy.position_size == -1)
is_in_trade = strategy.position_size != 0

if (is_new_trade)
    highest_close := close
    lowest_close := close

if (is_in_trade)
    highest_close := close > highest_close ? close : highest_close
    lowest_close := close < lowest_close ? close : lowest_close

plot(highest_close, color=color.green)
plot(lowest_close, color=color.red)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir, with your code i was able to get what i was looking for. May all the bird droppings magically avoid hitting your car for the rest of your life.