# PineScript Highest-High and Lowest-Low showing Current-High and Current-Low

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have the following code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
varip int left = 0
varip float highestHigh = na
varip float lowestLow   = na

left := left + 1
highestHigh := ta.highest(high, left)
lowestLow   := ta.lowest (low,  left)

plot(highestHigh, "Highest High", color=color.orange)

if (left >= 4)
    left := 0
```

Here, if `left = 3`, I should get the `highestHigh` and `lowestLow` for `length` equal to `3`, but it shows the `highestHigh` and `lowestLow` for just the current candle.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you're using `varip`, which means your script gets updates on each data update (like secondwise) and you reach your max 4 on the same bar - if you're not on a couple of secs timeframe - so you have no chance to get to the 4th bar from the right.
I don't know what the intention behind `varip` was but I think you could/should use `var` instead which does almost the same, meaning it keeps the value you assigned to the variable BUT unlike varip it updates on a bar base and intrabar data update is not kept to the next bar. So your `var left` will be as follows: on the 1st bar 0, on the 2nd 1, on the 3rd 2 etc. `varip left` is always 1 in your highest calculation.
Second problem is that it is possible that you only get the highest value for the current bar each time when your counter gets reset to 0 again. It depends on what you want to achieve by that.

UPDATE
@vitruvius offers an alternative solution for the dynamic length problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73271652/15348203

Comment: I don't think the counter is getting reset, have a look at the image - https://i.imgur.com/Po48eNy.png here the counter 'left' is being plotted which shows that it is not reset everytime, still the HighestHigh is not correct. I am basically trying to plot the highestHigh value for a number of candles which depends on the variable 'left'

Comment: Either way the counter gets reset for sure. If you stick to varip (that makes no sense to me) it gets reset on the same bar at value of 1 and neves makes it further. If you modify it to var your counter works fine. The problem seems to be with the native ta.highest() function of tradingview with the dynamic length. It wonders me why that wouldn't work. Alternative solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73271652/15348203

Comment: Got confused with the above code. I tried changing varip to var for left variable but it did not work. Anyway, I made the code to manually find the highest value by using if statement and it works. Thanks for the help though